# S3 Bulk putObject

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am profiling my Java distributed crawler (that stores crawled documents in S3), and S3 insertion is definitely a bottleneck. In fact, at high enough number of threads, the threads will consistently get timeout exception from S3 due to the fact that it takes too long for S3 to read the data. Is there a bulk `putObject` function provided by either Amazon or another library that can do this more efficiently?

Example code:

```
BUCKET = ...; // S3 bucket definition
AmazonS3 client= ...;

InputStream is = ...; // convert the data into input stream
ObjectMetadata meta = ...; // get metadata
String key = ...;

client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET, key, is, meta));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used S3 with java but AWS does support multipart uploads for large files.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html

The boto library for Python does support this for sure. I've used it to successfully upload very very large database backups before.

After looking at the javadocs for the java library I think you may need to use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/UploadPartRequest.html instead of the regular request and you can get the multipart upload going.

Comment: I want more along the lines of putting multiple object in one request. Currently I keep getting socket timeout because I have more than 100 threads trying to do put object at once.. Do you know if this is possible?